# Spring Boot : Can I bypass my module name and expose rest controller name?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Ex :Refer below url : www.abc.com:93/xyz/restApi/doSomthing
Wan to replace these with :  www.abc.com:93/restApi/doSomthing

where xyz is my microservice name , and @RestController @RequestMapping("/restApi") is my path for rest controller

Comment: In monolithic application Rest services are expose without module name it look like I have to change my microservice name from xyz -> restApi is there any alternative way

Comment: If the RequestMapping path is /restApi, then a typical Spring boot application will expose the resource at /restApi, not at /xyz/restApi. If it does, it's probably that you're deploying as a war file, in a non-standalone container, under a context path and not as ROOT. I.e. you explicitly chose to do things the non-standard way. Spring Boot doesn't have any notion of a microservice. That's something you chose to define that way.

Comment: Thanks JB ,I had done it by changing module name

Answer (score 0):

by changing context path in .yaml file Issue was resolved